# I did a step function FFT on matlab but only getting one side of the spectrum (0 to infinity)

Tags: matlab, fft

with this code i am only getting half og the fft spectrum from 0 to positive infinity . i am trying to mirror this along the y axis to get the other half which is symmetric to this one from 0 to negative infinity.

```
    Fs = 1000;   %sampling rate
    Ts = 1/Fs; %sampling time interval
    t = -10:Ts:10-Ts; %sampling period
    n = length(t); %number of samples
    y = heaviside(t)-heaviside(t-4); %the step curve

    matlabFFT = figure;  %create a new figure
    YfreqDomain = fft(y); %take the fft of our step funcion, y(t)
    y=abs(YfreqDomain);
    plot(y)
    xlabel('Sample Number')
    ylabel('Amplitude')
    title('Using the Matlab fft command')
    grid
    axis([-100,100,0,5000])
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's normal behaviour. The FFT returns the spectrum in positive frequencies only (between 0 and Fs). You can use `fftshift` to correct that. The zero frequency will then be at the center of the x axis. So you should use

```
plot(fftshift(y))
axis([-100+1e4,100+1e4,0,5000])
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much this worked. now how can i make my x-axis(sample number) in term of pi instead of from(-100+1e4,100+1e4)....man you saved my life this project is due tomorow!!

Comment: The complete frequency axis of the FFT with `fftshift` should be [-pi, pi]. So use `plot(linspace(-pi,pi,length(y)),fftshift(y))` and then something like `axis([-.03,.03,0,5000])`

Comment: Thanks luis i have one last question: i want to make my code dependable of the number of FFT points i want to graph so i can observe the difference it makes when you have more or less points. similar to what they did in this document: http://www.ele.uri.edu/~hansenj/projects/ele436/fft.pdf

Comment: i did this 'YfreqDomain = fft(y,n)' where n is the number of samples  'n = 200; %number of samples' but i am only seeing a straight line what do you think i did wrong here? Thank you so much

Comment: @LuisMendo I am having a problem with a similar issue here, and your nice simple solution here makes me wonder if you might be able to help :) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52318628/matlab-fourier-coefficient-values-oscillating

Comment: @neuronet I don't have much time right now, but it looks you got a good answer from Cris Luengo, who is very knowledgeable about signal processing